# Oracle iterates thru values on columns

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have some data like this

```
NO| ID    | PID | COUNT
1 | 00033 | P4  | 1
2 | 00033 | P3  | 3
3 | 00033 | P2  | 2
```

i want to iterate the ID and PID based on count values, like this

```
NO| ID    | PID
1 | 00033 | P4
2 | 00033 | P3
3 | 00033 | P3
4 | 00033 | P3
5 | 00033 | P2
6 | 00033 | P2
```

hows the best way to achieve this using Oracle PL/SQL procedure / cursor.

Regards,
Rian

Answer (score 1):

Use plain SQL:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY t."ID", t."PID" DESC ) as NO, 
       t."ID", t."PID"
FROM Table1 t
CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT 1 FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= t."COUNT"
)
ORDER BY t."ID", t."PID" DESC
```

demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d0840879efd2ef4dbc9caef4d1ff6a50

Comment: i never know the cross apply and connect by. im gonna take this answer. thanks

Comment: HI this SQL working on Oracle 12. how about know oracle 11 version ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution with CURSOR FOR LOOP and nested FOR loop, in a procedure:

**Table**

```
create table nipc ( no, id, pid, count )
as
select 1 , '00033' , 'P4'  , 1 from dual union all
select 2 , '00033' , 'P3'  , 3 from dual union all
select 3 , '00033' , 'P2'  , 2 from dual ;
```

**Procedure**

```
create or replace procedure nloops
is
begin
  for r in ( select no, id, pid, count from nipc )
  loop
    for iter in 1 .. r.count
    loop
      dbms_output.put_line( r.no || ' | ' || r.id || ' | ' || r.pid  ) ; 
    end loop ;
  end loop ;
end ;
/
```

**Test w/ anonymous block**

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    nloops ;
  3  end;
  4  /
1 | 00033 | P4
2 | 00033 | P3
2 | 00033 | P3
2 | 00033 | P3
3 | 00033 | P2
3 | 00033 | P2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

[DBfiddle here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a1642643a87bbace6dd775627aac9191)

You know that you should "use SQL whenever possible" before writing any PL/SQL code (eg see @krokodilko's answer).