# Oracle iterates thru values on columns (Oracle 11)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

So I have some data like this

```
NO| ID    | PID | COUNT
1 | 00033 | P4  | 1
2 | 00033 | P3  | 3
3 | 00033 | P2  | 2
```

i want to iterate the ID and PID based on count values, like this

```
NO| ID    | PID
1 | 00033 | P4
2 | 00033 | P3
3 | 00033 | P3
4 | 00033 | P3
5 | 00033 | P2
6 | 00033 | P2
```

actually its already solved using this query

```
SELECT row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY t."ID", t."PID" DESC ) as NO, 
       t."ID", t."PID"
FROM Table1 t
CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT 1 FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= t."COUNT"
)
ORDER BY t."ID", t."PID" DESC
```

as per this link
[Oracle iterates thru values on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025996/oracle-iterates-thru-values-on-columns)

but since our DB using oracle 11. the code doesnt working anymore.

i'd like to know the same approach for oracle 11.

Regards, Rian

Answer (score 4):

Cast this hierarchical query as table of numbers and then join:

```
with 
  t("NO", "ID", "PID", "COUNT") as (
    select 1, '00033', 'P4', 1 from dual union all
    select 2, '00033', 'P3', 3 from dual union all
    select 3, '00033', 'P2', 2 from dual ),
  a as (select t.*, 
               cast(multiset(select level lvl 
                             from dual 
                             connect by level <= "COUNT") 
                    as sys.odcinumberlist) nums 
          from t)
select "NO", "ID", "PID" from a cross join table(nums)
```

Result:

```
        NO ID    PID
---------- ----- ---
         1 00033 P4
         2 00033 P3
         2 00033 P3
         2 00033 P3
         3 00033 P2
         3 00033 P2
6 rows selected
```